# Where V is a Vector Space, $\forall \overrightarrow{v} \in V, 0\overrightarrow{v} = \overrightarrow{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, proof-writing

I'm denoting all vectors as such: $\overrightarrow{v}$. Any variable without an arrow above is a scalar. Suppose $V$ is a vector space over $F$, with additive identities $\overrightarrow{0}$ and $0$ respectively.

I'm trying to show that $\forall \overrightarrow{v} \in V, 0\cdot \overrightarrow{v} = \overrightarrow{0}$.

I'm confused. I know how to prove this for a normal scalar in a Field ($\forall a \in F, a0=0$) but I'm not sure how to carry out the proof for a vector space. I read the following:
$$0\overrightarrow{v} = (0+0)\overrightarrow{v} = 0\overrightarrow{v} + 0\overrightarrow{v}$$ But I don't see how this implies the proposition. Can anyone help me clear this up? It might just be the notation - the book I'm using is not doing a great job at typographically differentiating between the additive identity for vectors and the one for scalars.

Answer (score 3):

Any vector space is a group under addition, right? The zero vector $\overrightarrow{0}$ being the neutral element: $\overrightarrow{v} + \overrightarrow{0} = \overrightarrow{v}$, for all $\overrightarrow{v}$. Ok?

That means that if you have an equality like

$$
a + b = a + c
$$

you can cancel both $a$ and obtain

$$
b = c \ .
$$

So, what happens when you have an equality like

$$
a + b = a \quad \text{?}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I ended up proving this with little reference to the other answers. Retrospectively, a main point of confusion was that I wasn't sure whether $0 \cdot \overrightarrow{v}$ even was a vector! Anyway, here's the **Proof:**

$$0 \cdot \overrightarrow{v} = (0+0)\cdot \overrightarrow{v}$$
$$0 \cdot \overrightarrow{v} = (0 \cdot \overrightarrow{v}) + (0 \cdot \overrightarrow{v})$$
We know from the axioms that if $a \in F$, $\overrightarrow{b} \in V$, then $(a \cdot \overrightarrow{b}) \in V$. So $0 \cdot \overrightarrow{v}$ is a vector, i.e. $0 \cdot \overrightarrow{v} \in V$. We also know that this vector has an additive inverse, $\overrightarrow{-v} \in V$, such that $\overrightarrow{v} + \overrightarrow{-v} = \overrightarrow{0}$. It follows that:
$$(0 \cdot \overrightarrow{v}) + -(0 \cdot \overrightarrow{v}) = (0 \cdot \overrightarrow{v}) +(0 \cdot \overrightarrow{v}) + -(0 \cdot \overrightarrow{v})$$
$$\Longrightarrow \overrightarrow{0} = (0 \cdot \overrightarrow{v})$$

Comment: This is correct, and the obvious thing to do. You shouldn't have any doubt about $0\vec v$ being a vector: you obtained it in the first place by valid applications of operations (scalar multiplication with a scalar on the left and a vector on the right) so it is a valid expression; moreover the operation used (scalar multiplication) yields a vector.

Answer (score 1):

In the field $0 + 0 = 0$, where $o$ is the additive identity of the field.

$0.v$ is an element of $V$ which is a vector space with addition.

$0.v = (0 + 0 ).v = 0.v + 0.v$ because of property of external composition $.$.

Which gives $0.v - 0.v = 0.v$.

We have $V$ is a group under addition where the additive identity is $\overrightarrow{0}$, and $ - 0.v$ is the additive invars of $0.v$ so $0.v - 0.v = \overrightarrow{0}$

Thus we have $0.v = \overrightarrow{0}$ and we use to write $0.v = 0$ assuming first $0$ from the field and second $0$ from the vector space.

Comment: Why down vote here? please show reason.

Comment: I wrote that I am having difficulty with this because my book is not differentiating between $0$, the additive identity for the Field, and $\overrightarrow{0}$, the additive identity for the Vector Space (the zero vector). Please improve your notation to make your answer clearer.

Comment: Let me make a suitable correction.

Comment: Error is fixed. Hope your doubt is clear now.

Comment: That's clearer. Thanks